# Types issue in F#

Tags: .net, f#, types

In my ongoing adventure deep diving into f# I am understanding a lot of this powerful language but there are things that I still do not understand so clearly.
One of the most important issues I need to master is types.

Well the book I am reading is very straight forward and introduces entities and main functionalities with a direct approach. The first thing I could get start with is types. It introduces the main types as list, option, tuples, and so on...
It is clearly underlined that all these types are IMMUTABLE for many reasons regarding functional programming and data consistance in functional programing. Well, no problems until now...

But now I am getting started with Concrete Types...

Well... I have problems in managing with types like list, option, tuples, types created through new operator and concrete types created using type keyword (for abbreviations, concrete types...).

So my question is: how can I efficently catalogue/distinguish all types of data in f#????

I can create a perfect separation among types in C#, VB.NET...
FOr example in VB.NET there are value and reference types while in C# there are only references and also int, double are treated as objects (they are objects while in VB.NET a value type is not a object and there is a split in types for this reason).
Well in F# I cannot create such differences among types in the language.
Can you help me? I hope I was clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The challenge of hybrid functional/object-oriented languages like F# is that they must span *both* functional *and* object-oriented concepts. Although this makes such languages very powerful, it also makes them large; larger than strictly functional languages or strictly OO languages. One place that is most evident is the type catalog.

The official documention for F# types is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233230.aspx). As you can see, there are no less than 17 different types of...types.

One thing to keep in mind, though, is that any type that can be defined or used in F# must be representable as a .NET type (which implies that it can also be used by other .NET languages). An interesting example of that is [Discriminated Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233226.aspx) types (discriminated union types are similar to enumerations, except that each alternate value can have other values associated to it). Other .NET languages do not have discriminated union types, so the F# compiler translates such types to object hierarchies. Something gets lost in the translation, though: F# 'knows' all possible cases of the type at compile time, but C# and VB.NET must assume that the number of cases is open-ended.

Comment: "Kind" is usually used to describe the "type" of a type... (Well, often used, in a particular context, but nevertheless it will get you close enough if you are searching).

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that you've misunderstood types in C# and VB.NET. Types work almost the same across all .NET languages; for instance, both VB.NET and C# have value types and reference types.

Any type can be immutable if there's no way to change it from outside. For instance, these two pieces of code are equivalent:

```
// an immutable reference type in F#
type Person =
    {
        FirstName : string
        LastName : string
    }

// an immutable reference type in C#
public class Person
{
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }
}
```

**Edit:** There's nothing really special about the built-in types in F#, except for some special syntax in the compiler. You can make your own - here are examples of [`list`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee370372.aspx) and [`option`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee353806.aspx):

```
type List<'a> = Empty
              | Item of 'a * List<'a>

type Option<'a> = None
                | Some of 'a
```

It helps to take an F# assembly and load it into Reflector, alongside assemblies from C# and VB.NET; you can see that the compiler produces standard .NET types from your F# type declarations.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

For a good reference of the different types in F#, scroll down to **F# Types** on the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233181.aspx). I've found that the MSDN site really does have some of the best information about F# out there. To summarize, you've got F#'s own flavor of collections (i.e. `Map`, `Seq`, etc), [tuples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233200.aspx) (which are just a like cross product of several types), discriminated unions, and more.

F# uses [type inference](http://en.csharp-online.net/FSharp_Functional_Programming%E2%80%94Types_and_Type_Inference), so you do not need to explicitly specify the type your member variables in a type/class. This means, that in most scenarios you do not need to specify that  variable is an `int`, `double`, or any reference type like you would in C#. The distinction between reference types and value types is hidden from you basically.

Also, when you say:

> VB.NET there are value and reference types while in C# there are only references

This isn't exactly accurate, it's actually the same in VB.NET/C#, see [Jon Skeet's article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html#preamble1) about reference vs. value types for a really clear explanation.

Comment: I mean that I know how many kind of types there are in C# or VB.NET but in F# I could not figure that out yet. I mean thet there are mutable, immutable types. But also all types coming from the .NET libraries that use the <- assignment operators... So I do not know how to move in this labyrinth of types...

Comment: OK regarding what I said about c# and vb.net types.... I was in a hurry and wrote a very stupid thing... I meant that in all .net languages there are reference and value types but while in vb.net value types are types on their own in c# all types are part of a global hierarchy... in c# int is a an instance of Int32 which inherits from Object... while this is not valid in VB.NET... int, double and so on are not wrapped by Int32 or other classes, they are different types and are not part of the class library

Comment: @Andry, sorry, but I think you're still on the wrong track with regard to C# and VB.NET. The relationship between int and Int32 and Object can be confusing, for sure, but it's exactly the same between C# and VB.NET.

Comment: OK, well... I was wrong... I'm hapy... I could get things clear in one question. I always thought that VB.NET defined types out of the class lib... well I trusted an articles years ago that was wrong it seems... Sorry for the trouble and thank you Mr. Pratt for your information. :)